# Overlay polygons as sf object in r-plotly

Tags: r, plotly, maps

I'd like to overlay a map of Pangea on a standard plotly map. The code below works, but I can't control the line color or the fills on either map. Any ideas?

```
library(sf)
library(plotly)

pangea <- st_read("https://gws.gplates.org/reconstruct/coastlines_low/?&time=200&model=SETON2012&avoid_map_boundary")
st_crs(pangea) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"

plot_geo(pangea) %>% layout(geo = 
    list(projection = list(
      type = 'orthographic')
      ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to change linetype and color

```
plot_geo(pangea, color = I("red"), fill=I("white"), linetype = I("dash")) %>% 
  layout(geo = list(projection = list(
                                type = 'orthographic')
                              ))
```

Comment: On my end this throws an error

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

2: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

Comment: This is not an error but a warning.

Comment: But plot_geo(pangea_leaflet, color = I("red"), fill=I("white"))  works

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: I'm still stuck on fill color for the polgyons: plot_geo(pangea, color = I("red"), fill=I("red"), linetype = I("dash")) %>% 
  layout(geo = list(projection = list(
    type = 'orthographic')
  )) doesn't change the fill to red. Where is this documented?

Comment: Removing `fill=I("red")` gives red color fill.

Comment: Yes but just the polygons ... this fills the entire world! plot_geo(pangea, stroke = I("grey"), color=I("red")) %>% 
  layout(geo = list(projection = list(
    type = 'orthographic')
  ))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249061/discussion-between-mark-r-and-user-10085).